# Laravel возвращает 404 при обращении к api/register из Postman

Tags: php, laravel

У меня есть список роутов

```
POST       _ignition/execute-solution ........................................................................................... ignition.executeSolution › Spatie\LaravelIgnition › ExecuteSolutionController  
  GET|HEAD   _ignition/health-check ....................................................................................................... ignition.healthCheck › Spatie\LaravelIgnition › HealthCheckController
  POST       _ignition/update-config .................................................................................................... ignition.updateConfig › Spatie\LaravelIgnition › UpdateConfigController  
  GET|HEAD   api/admin/entities ...................................................................................................................................................... Api\EntityController@index  
  POST       api/admin/entities ...................................................................................................................................................... Api\EntityController@store  
  GET|HEAD   api/csrf-cookie ........................................................................................................................................ Laravel\Sanctum › CsrfCookieController@show  
  POST       api/login ................................................................................................................................................................. Api\AuthController@login  
  POST       api/register ........................................................................................................................................................... Api\AuthController@register
```

когда я общаюсь методом GET к странице `https://app-local.ru/api/register`, получаю ошибку что метод не поддерживается, и нужно обратиться методом POST, то есть система видит этот роут при выполнении запросов.

Но если я отправляю запрос методом POST то приходит 404.

сам метод контроллера выглядит вот так

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function register(Request $request): \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
    {

        $request->validate([
            'name'     => 'required|string',
            'email'    => 'required|email:rfc,dns|string|unique:users,email',
            'password' => 'required|string|confirmed',
        ]);

        $user = User::create([
            'name'     => $request->name,
            'email'    => $request->email,
            'password' => bcrypt($request->password),
        ]);

        Auth::attempt($request->only('email', 'password'));

        return response()->json($user);
    }
```

При этом, если я просто верну какой-то массив вместо регистрации пользователя, то массив возвращается, но если снова пытаюсь выполнить проверку, а затем зарегистрировать пользователя, то получаю 404

Comment: Это из-за использования [$request->validate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61783651/laravel-throws-404-when-request-validate-fails). Вам нужно создавать валидатор через Validator::make, и туда передавать данные для проверки.